# Wine not finding some files

Tags: linux, gentoo, wine

I'm having strange issues with Wine :

If I look a `C:\windows\system32\drivers\` in `wine explorer`, the directory looks empty, while the directory `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/drivers` is not.

Plus, having the `H:` drive mapped to my home directory, I can look at `H:\.wine\drive_c\windows\system32\drivers` and it is not empty, the files are here ! Thus it seems Wine has the rights to access these files.

So why don't they appear on the `C:` drive ? Some of my programs need them.

I'm using Gentoo Linux, and Wine is version 1.7.0 compiled with these useflags (from `eix`) :

```
X alsa cups fontconfig gecko jpeg lcms ldap mono mp3 ncurses nls openal opengl
perl png prelink run-exes ssl threads truetype udisks xcomposite xinerama xml
-capi -custom-cflags -dos -gphoto2 -gsm -gstreamer -odbc -opencl -osmesa -oss
-pulseaudio -samba -scanner -selinux -test -v4l
ABI_MIPS="-n32 -n64 -o32"
ABI_X86="32 64 -x32"
ELIBC="glibc"
```

EDIT: I just updated to wine 1.7.4 and nothing changed.

Comment: I had  a similar issue the first time I run `wine explorer`, but I can see the files now. I have wine-core-1.7.2-1.fc19.x86_64 and other wine* packages on Fedora 19.